# How to get datatype and data length of the columns of Dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, validation

I am trying to fetch the **datatype** and **datalength** of the columns of **dataframe** in the format like **object(10)** where **10 is the data length and object is the type of dataframe**. I am using **dtype function** to get datatype of the columns but not getting the length of the columns using this.

```
dct=df.dtype.apply(lambda x:x.name).to_dict()
```

from here I am only getting datatype as **object,int64,datetime64[ns]**.

but the expected result is **object(),int64()** etc like we do SQL to create a table. example **object(6),int64(10)** where 6 is the datalength and object is datatype.

can anyone guide me on this?

Data:
A   X   Y   Z
1   Raju    Yes Local
2   Ram No  Resident
3   Rohan   Approved    Citizen

Output:
{'A':int(1),'X':string(6),'Y':string(8),'Z':string(8)}

in string data length =max(data present in particular columns)
ex:
Y:string(max_length(data present in y))
Y:string(8)

Comment: concept `datalength` in pandas not exist, no method exist for count it.But some custom function should be created, but I guess ouput should be different like  datalength in SQL. Can you add some data sample with expected output?

Comment: @jezrael I have added the data and expected result in the Question.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

```
#selected only integers and object columns
df1 = df.select_dtypes([object, np.integer])

#dtypes
s1 = df1.dtypes.apply(lambda x:x.name)
#maximal length of data
s2  = df1.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.len()).max()

#dict comprehension

d = {k: f'string({b})' if a == 'object' 
                       else f'int({b})' 
                       for k, a , b in zip(s1.index, s1, s2)}
print (d)
{'A': 'int(1)', 'X': 'string(5)', 'Y': 'string(8)', 'Z': 'string(8)'}
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael but this will not give me the datatype and data length for all columns in dataframe .

Comment: yes, the structure is really same as but instead of object, string instead of on int64  int only but that great really helpful. super @jezrael..